# Как заставить работать MSSQL?

Tags: php

Установлен денвер, качала по ссылке "последняя версия" с пхп5 
Обращаюсь к mssql

echo("Hello, World!" ); 
$qqq=mssql_connect("user","","");

В ответ получаю : 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in

Подскажите как исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В php.ini найдите строку ";extension=php_mssql.dll" и раскомментируйте (уберите ";" в начале строки). После этого денвер надо перезагрузить.

Comment: он уже раскомментирован

Answer (score 0):

К тому же проверьте есть ли такой dll файл в папке с расшерениями PHP...

Comment: такой файл есть и он раскомментирован, но все равно не работает

Comment: Я подключал эту библиотеку, на сайте майкрософт есть документация по MS SQLSERVER, проверяли в phpinfo() подключена ли эта библиотека?

Comment: mssql_connect() - это верный синтаксис(у вас так и есть), стало быть не подключена библиотека ... 1) проверьте еще раз все ли верно указано 2) поищите, насколько помню нужно еще и учитывать архитектуру процессора при подключении библиотеки, поэтому посетите сайт разработчика СУБД.

Answer (score 0):

Если в конфигах все ок но MSSQL функции не определяет, то тебе надо скачать более новую версию либы ntwdblib.dll, если её нету вообще то скачай в папку где лежит само php5 например c:/AppServ/php5/ntwdblib.dll